# Intercept all method calls for all metaclasses in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to intercept all method calls inside Groovy scripts running in a Java environment.

Specially I want to check the return type of all method calls, and if it is `X` I want to replace it with `Y`.

I know you can intercept using `invokeMethod` on the MetaClass, but I can only do that to the script class that I compile. If the script in turn calls a method on class `A` then it will create a new `MetaClass[A]` that I can't intercept without earlier having manually fetched that MetaClass from the registry and overriding it with a meta method.

I have tried to use `GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry()` to add listeners for when MetaClasses are created, to add meta methods there, but it seemingly never fires.

I would like this to be automatic, and not in advance having to add an annotation to the methods that I should transform, or knowing which classes' methods I want to transform. All methods that return `X` should return `Y`.

Can I globally intercept all method calls?

Can I intercept MetaClass creation instead?

Can I add automatic AST transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is possible. You need to replace the MetaClassCreationHandle by calling `GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().setMetaClassCreationHandle`.

Since the base class `MetaClassCreationHandle` is package private, it might be easier to extend from `ExpandoMetaClassCreationHandle` instead. But take into consideration that it might be overkill for your most common need to make all your classes be based on the `ExpandoMetaClass`. So what I did was something like this:

```
GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().setMetaClassCreationHandle(new ExpandoMetaClassCreationHandle() {

    @Override
    protected MetaClass createNormalMetaClass(Class theClass, MetaClassRegistry registry) {

        final List<Method> propertyMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Method method : theClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.getReturnType() == TheMethodReturnTypeYouCareAbout.class) {
                propertyMethods.add(method);
            }
        }

        final MetaClass mc;
        if (propertyMethods.isEmpty() == false) {

            final ExpandoMetaClass expando = new ExpandoMetaClass(theClass, true, true);
            for (Method mm : propertyMethods) {
                final ClassInfo ci = ClassInfo.getClassInfo(mm.getDeclaringClass());
                expando.addMetaMethod(new MetaMethod() {

                    @Override
                    public int getModifiers() {
                        return mm.getModifiers();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getName() {
                        return mm.getName();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Class getReturnType() {
                        return mm.getReturnType();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public CachedClass getDeclaringClass() {
                        return ci.getCachedClass();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Class[] getPT() {
                        return mm.getParameterTypes();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object invoke(Object object, Object[] arguments) {
                        try {
                            final Object value = mm.invoke(object, arguments);
                            // Do whatever you need with the value.
                            return value;
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            mc = expando;
        } else if (GeneratedClosure.class.isAssignableFrom(theClass)) {
            mc = new ClosureMetaClass(registry, theClass);
        } else {
            mc = new MetaClassImpl(registry, theClass);
        }

        return mc;
    }
});
```

This means that we will only create Expando classes for those that we have a need of adding meta methods to.