# Groovy technique for forwarding all methods to an encapsulated object?

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-class, metaclass, subclassing

I have a `TreeTableView` subclass. I want to use a `SelectionModel` for this in which certain methods throw exceptions if an attempt to use them is made (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60954005/595305) for reason why).

Rather unfortunately, class `TreeTableView.TreeTableViewSelectionModel` is `abstract`. My "start" at trying to deliver such a concrete class is this:

```
class MyTreeTableSelectionModel extends TreeTableView.TreeTableViewSelectionModel {
    final static String PROHIBITED_METHOD_MSG = 'Method is prohibited due to problems with internal JavaFX NPEs. Use select( row, column ) instead.'
    TreeTableView.TreeTableViewSelectionModel suppliedConcreteModel

    MyTreeTableSelectionModel(TreeTableView treeTableView) {
        super( treeTableView )
        assert treeTableView.selectionModel != null
        suppliedConcreteModel = treeTableView.selectionModel
    }

    @Override
    ObservableList<TreeTablePosition> getSelectedCells() {
        suppliedConcreteModel.getSelectedCells()
    }

    @Override
    boolean isSelected(int row, TableColumnBase column) {
        suppliedConcreteModel.isSelected( row, column )
    }

    @Override
    void select(int row, TableColumnBase column) {
        suppliedConcreteModel.select( row, column )
    }

    @Override
    void clearAndSelect(int row, TableColumnBase column) {
        suppliedConcreteModel.clearAndSelect( row, column )
    }

    @Override
    void clearSelection(int row, TableColumnBase column) {
        suppliedConcreteModel.clearSelection( row, column )
    }

    @Override
    void selectLeftCell() {
        suppliedConcreteModel.selectLeftCell()
    }

    @Override
    void selectRightCell() {
        suppliedConcreteModel.selectRightCell()
    }

    @Override
    void selectAboveCell() {
        suppliedConcreteModel.selectAboveCell()
    }

    @Override
    void selectBelowCell() {
        suppliedConcreteModel.selectBelowCell()
    }

    @Override
    void select( int row ){
        throw new Exception( PROHIBITED_METHOD_MSG )
    }

    @Override
    void selectFirst(){
        throw new Exception( PROHIBITED_METHOD_MSG )
    }

    @Override
    void selectLast(){
        throw new Exception( PROHIBITED_METHOD_MSG )
    }
}
```

... this (obviously) doesn't work as implemented: the implemented overridden `abstract` methods forward calls to the encapsulated object `suppliedConcreteModel`, but the other methods (of which there are maybe 50 or so), and all properties and fields, are forwarded to the concrete object of class `MyTreeTableSelectionModel`.

Is there any Groovy way of forwarding all methods, fields and properties to the encapsulated object? I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47991022/595305), but I don't fully understand it, or whether it is actually relevant, and I suspect there is a more "orthodox" Groovy way of doing what I want.

Comment: Have you tried `@Delegate`?

Comment: Thanks. Powerful annotation, and I had no knowledge of it. First experiments quite baffling. Would you care to make an answer if you can see the solution (and not totally "on strike")?

Comment: I haven't used it in a situation as complicated as yours and don't think I can make a competent writeup for your case. A self-answer here seems that it would be suitable if it works.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- +1 for `@Delegate`.  you could answer by quoting the docs.